# Break longer word into lines to fit the box (inputminted?)

Tags: listings, minted, highlighting, framed, sourcecode

I would like to fit the long string (as it is labelled url in the json file) inside the box without overflowing. As far as I understand, `breaklines` option only helps when strings consist of separated words. How about the longer words as in url scenario ? In the example, how can I split the url into more lines in order to fit them into the page or preferably inside the box ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}%
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Data Format}

\begin{document}

    \begin{listing}[H]    
        \inputminted[frame=lines,
                       framesep=2mm,
                       fontsize=\footnotesize,
                       linenos=true,
                       breaklines=true,
                       xleftmargin=21pt,
                       tabsize=1]{json}{code/test.json} 
        \label{list:bbbbbbbbbb}
    \end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Example content of the test file: (`test.json`)

```
{  
    "cID"               : 1,
    "test"              : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa          bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc",
    "url"               : "http://www.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc.com"
}
```

It generates overflow for the url field:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add also option `breakanywhere=true` (default value is `false`, thats why it is not active right away). Refer to page 15 and forward in `fvextra` pacakge documentation (same author as `minted`, and `minted` is using this package behind the scenes).

This option can also be set globaly. You might be also interested in command `\breakanywheresymbolpre`and simillar (refer to docs).

Heres the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}%
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Data Format}

\begin{document}

    \begin{listing}[H]    
        \inputminted[frame=lines,
                       framesep=2mm,
                       fontsize=\footnotesize,
                       linenos=true,
                       breaklines=true,
                       breakanywhere=true,
                       xleftmargin=21pt,
                       tabsize=1]{json}{code/test.json} 
        \label{list:bbbbbbbbbb}
    \end{listing}

\end{document}
```